# Giving value to text boxes in forms using Flask and Python

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, flask-wtforms

I have a HTML page where I have 5 text boxes which I want to be populated with data from my MongoDB database.
The structure is so :

```
app/
 templates/
  *.html (All HTML Templates here)
 forms.py
 views.py
run.py
```

All the forms are stored in forms.py file. The views.py file has the route. When the user clicks on a certain html page, the text boxes should already have value which should come from the Database. I am not able to figure out how to populate those.

I am using flask-wtf for forms. Here is the code for the forms.py file -- https://github.com/rahulw/Inventory-Management-for-a-Store/blob/master/app/forms.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't really matter what DB you're using. Basically, what you need to do is change this attribute of your form:

```
form.post_body.data = page_content['body']
```

Where page_content is the stuff you've pulled from the DB, post_body is your specific form field you want to populate, and form is of course your form.

You'd then throw this form into the view like you normally would, and the data will be populated!

Comment: @ryan-odonnell That worked for me. Thank you. What I am stuck with is, that when new values are entered in that form and the submit button is clicked, the new values in the text boxes is not taken but the old one which was printed is taken. I wanted to update the values in the databases but wanted to show it to the user first before editing it and saving him the pain from entering all the values again but just editing the required values. Do you have any suggestion to this?

Comment: Rahul, it is hard to know exactly without loading up your app and doing some debugging, but I'm guessing you're forgetting a `if request.method == 'POST'` or something like that and you're over-writing your values AFTER the post request is sent. When you get your questions answered here everyone likes it if you mark them as correct :)